# Dropdown list checkbox event not getting triggered on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am having a `dropdown` list on the header of data table. The list has multiple `checkbox` and I want to call an event when the checkbox is `checked` or `unchecked`.

During debug, breakpoint is not hitting the checkbox click event. Please let me know how to implement for checkbox `click/change` event in this scenario.

Comment: Try binding on `body` instead, that way you will catch the event after DOM change: `$("body").on("click", "#chk_select_abst", function () { ... });`

Comment: cannot be bound on body since the dropdown values load after the data table has loaded on a button click event. Any approach to get the event called in the above setup?

Comment: yes, it can and it should. you didn't even try to do it, that's a shame :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `#chk_select_abst` is not rendered at the time of DOM ready when you are binding that event.

For binding events on dynamically added DOMs, you can `bind` or `delegate` the event somewhere on its `parent` DOM node which you are sure will be there on page load and will **NEVER** be removed/replaced dynamically. Behind the scenes, this make use of `event bubbling` or `event propagation`. [Check out this link for more info about bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

A safe bet is to use the parent node as `body`. But, you can and should use a lower parent node (in this case `#ul_AbandonedStates`) for performance gain.

[Documentation for jQuery event delegation.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```js
var json = {
  abandonState: [{
    Name: 'name 1',
    Value: 'value 1'
  }, {
    Name: 'name 2',
    Value: 'value 2'
  }]
}

function addCheckBox() {
  if (json) {
    if (json.abandonState) {
      var abandonedStates = json.abandonState;
      var li = $('<li>');
      var select = $("<label><input id='chk_select_abst' type='checkbox' class='abandonstatecheckclass' value='-1' name='Select All' /> Select All</label>");
      var res = li.append(select);
      $('#ul_AbandonedStates').append(res);
      $.each(abandonedStates, function(index, item) {
        var li = $('<li>');
        var chk = $("<label><input id='chk_" + item.Value + "' type='checkbox' class='abandoncheckclass' value='" + item.Value + "' name='" + item.Name + "' />" + item.Name + "</label>");
        var res = li.append(chk);
        $('#ul_AbandonedStates').append(res);
      });
      var li = $('<li>');
      var btn = $('<button id="ul_AbandonedStates_ok" class="btn btn- primary btn- xs" type="button" value="OK">OK</button>');
      var res = li.append(btn);
      $('#ul_AbandonedStates').append(res);
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //change here
  $("#ul_AbandonedStates").on("click", "#chk_select_abst", function() {
    $("#ul_AbandonedStates input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th align="center" width="13%" style="position:relative;" index=6 name="abandonedState">
    Abandon State
    <div class="down-arrow-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="down-arrow" id="da-abandonstate"></a>
      <ul class="checkbox-list" id="ul_AbandonedStates"></ul>
    </div>
    <th>
</table>

<button class="add" onclick="addCheckBox()">Add List</button>
```